# RPI as a Cloud Server

Tags: server, setup

I'm **very** new to RPI and I found this link [here](http://blog.petrockblock.com/2012/08/15/your-own-cloud-server-with-owncloud-on-the-raspberry-pi/) to create my own Cloud Server, which is what I would love to do - it would be really useful for me. Given the steps and requirements on the page, what RPI setup would you suggest? I would also like a touch screen on the PI if that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a good power supply (i.e one with a 2.1A port), you would want a small battery backup potentially or a small standard UPS. The Raspberry Pi foundation has released a touchscreen for the Pi, it goes into the "other" camera port.

https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-78156/l/raspberry-pi-7-touchscreen-display

For network connectivity, I'd go with a direct ethernet connection, if it will be WiFi, make sure you have a good WiFi dongle.  You will also need to put together some sort of port-forwarding (router) configuration to get access to your pi from the web.

http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals

You will also be needing an external hard drive (I would assume).

Make a list of your requirements and make sure you do your research.  Plan for the project to take 10X longer to put together than you anticipate (especially since you are "very new").

Good luck

Comment: Awesome. I should learn quick, but I'll take my time. Appreciate the specifics!

Comment: Also, is it possible if you could recommend a specific PI or just find one as you suggested?

Comment: No reason not to use a Pi3b.  Also, be sure to have auto-patching enabled wherever possible and be careful how your firewall is configured (attempt to only whitelist essential services).  The big risk here is that you load this little device up with tons of personal info and then it gets pwned because some obscure app you aren't even using is running and open and has a big bad bug.

Comment: I wouldn't go with anything but the latest model to ensure you have the most horsepower for your application.  If that doesn't suit your needs (performance-wise) you might be better off going with an actual computer with the proper app-spec'd hardware.